Inconsistency between Powertools for Lambda (.NET) and EF Core interceptor
For example, I have a EF Core method like this
    [Tracing(CaptureMode = TracingCaptureMode.Error)] // AWS Powertools for tracking traces
    public async Task<TEntity> FindAsNoTrackingAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(expression)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

I also have an interceptor, just to track things about the query, the interceptor method
    public override ValueTask<DbDataReader> ReaderExecutedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, DbDataReader result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Tracing.WithSubsegment("EfCore", (subsegment) =>
        {
            EnrichTraceWithParameters(command, eventData);
        });
        return base.ReaderExecutedAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static void EnrichTraceWithParameters(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData)
    {
        Tracing.AddMetadata("Query", command.CommandText);
        Tracing.AddMetadata("Time", $"{(int)eventData.Duration.TotalMilliseconds} ms");

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (SqlParameter parameter in command.Parameters) 
        {
            var pValue = parameter.Value;
            if (pValue != null)
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}\n", parameter.ParameterName, pValue.ToString());
        }
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            Tracing.AddMetadata("Parameters", sb.ToString());
    }

My question is, the interceptor shows 23 ms for a query execution, however I'm seeing 1.12 s for FindAsNoTrackingAsync method in Cloudwatch Xray interface. I'm having quite hard time to understand why. Why would that method take too long? Could it be an issue about AWS Powertools library or some kind of network issue?
This is just an example though, I'm constantly receiving inconsistent numbers between trace duration and interceptor's query time.

Before executing ReaderExecutedAsync, EF Core should translate LINQ query, generate SQL, maybe intilize Model for the first time, then it should map result returned from database to objects.
